# Is that possible to run a selenium-based crawler script with python on AWS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, web-crawler, amazon-sagemaker

I want to build a web page crawler using python and host it on **AWS Sagemaker**. The reason behind using the **Selenium** package is that my target webpage blocks access to bots, and I have tried `requests`, `beautifulsoup`, and `scrapy`, and none of them work.

I tried downloading the related webdriver (e.g. `chromedriver` file) and uploading it to the notebook's executable path, using `os.get_exec_path()` and still when I run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/conda/bin/chromedriver')
```

I get the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

I have tried different solutions like headless mode and etc. and I have already tried similar Q&As in the stackoverflow. It seems like it is impossible to do that on the cloud. Just posting to get ideas if anyone has encountered the same situation.

Comment: Headless doesn't change file permissions, just how you run it. Have you tried the solutions in 3 duplicates marked? They actually mention permissions issues, not headless.